# Data ambiguous in SQL Like

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

I have one table,contains a field called ***Component***.The datas are -

```
date             component
----------------------------
2012/12/11       PRP,PU1,P
2012/12/12       PRP
```

I want to get  result like this-

```
date          P_QTY
-----------------------
2012/12/11    1
```

I try a query-

```
select date,count(date) as P_Qty    
from MyTable 
where component like '%P%'
group by date
```

but I get result-

```
date          P_QTY
-----------------------
2012/12/11    1
2012/12/12    1
```

There is ambiguous between `PRP` and `P`.
So, How can I remove ambiguous between `P` ,`PRP` and `PU1`?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you want `component` to be exactly because in both case there is `P`..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it is not the recommended way to store a one-to-many relationship between date and P_QTY.

To get the desired result, your query should be

```
SELECT date,count(date) as P_Qty    
FROM MyTable
where 
    (
        component = 'P' OR 
        component LIKE 'P,%' OR 
        component LIKE '%,P,%' OR 
        component LIKE '%,P'
    )
GROUP BY date
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to understand [% (Wildcard - Character)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276878%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) in detail:

> Matches any string of zero or more characters. This wildcard character can be used as either a prefix or a suffix.

Here is what you want:

```
select date,count(date) as P_Qty    
from MyTable 
where component like '%,P%'
group by date
```

### [Demo SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3079c/3)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select date,count(date) as P_Qty    
from MyTable 
where ',' + component + ',' like '%,P,%'
group by date
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are after:

```
select date,count(date) as P_Qty    
from MyTable 
where component = 'P' OR CHARINDEX(',P,', component) > 0  OR
      LEFT(component, 2) = 'P,' OR RIGHT(component,2) = ',P'
group by date
```

The same can be applied for other values. Just do not forget to change the integer values for LEFT and RIGHT functions. You could also introduce a variable that should be tested against. In this case, the integer values for LEFT and RIGHT functions will be the LEN() of this variable

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
select date,count(date) as P_Qty    
from MyTable 
where REPLACE(',' + component + ',', ' ', '') like '%,P,%'
group by date
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like your table is broken.  Get it into first normal form.  When each row has just one component in the `component` column, your query becomes trivial.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DATE,COUNT(*) AS P_QTY 
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE INSTR(COMPONENT,'PU1',1,1)>0
GROUP BY DATE
```